# Spring Data MongoDB query to match both number and numeric string

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

In my collection some documents are saved like:

```
{
  val: "1"
}

{
  val: "A"
}
```

And some others are like:

```
{
  val: 1
}
```

And in corresponding model class the field is declared as object:

```
class MyModel {
  @Id
  private String id;

  private Object val;
...
```

Right now I have a repository method:

```
@Query("{ val: ?0 }")
Page<MyModel> findByValue(Object val)
```

If I pass `val` as an integer to the repository method like `repo.findByValue(Integer.parseInt(valStr))` it doesn't find string numeric ones, if I don't then it doesn't find number ones. Is there a way to make a query which matches both numeric strings and actual numbers?

Comment: Depending upon the input value and the type of the document data, you can construct a query using an aggregation.

Comment: does the answer help you?

Answer (score 3):

You need to write two `findBy...` queries to get the values and combine them or you can easily develop an aggregation...

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      val: { $toString: "$val" }
    }
  },
  { $match: { val: "1" } }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RRvXrhe2qwn)**

And the java code is,

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public List<YOUR_CONVERTER_CLASS> test(String value) {

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(   
        project().and(ConvertOperators.ToString("val"))
            .as("val"),
        match(Criteris.where("val").is(value))
    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();

}
```

Note : This is not tested, but written based on the working mongo script